# Autoincrement ID with a prefix

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm designing a table 'employees', which contains an primary key which is auto increment and represents an ID of the employee.

I want to prefix the ID with an number designating the city: city 1: 1, city 2:2, etc.

So the IDs should look like xyy where x represents the city and yy the ID of the employee.

When I'm adding new employee I'm selecting the city x, and I would like to yy values to auto increment.

Is that possible using SQL commands?

Comment: Its called relational for a reason,what prevents you adding a city column?

Comment: Don't do this in your schema.  Just use identities.  You can generate a surrogate key as a value for your display ID.

Comment: And heaven help the employee in your 11th city.

Comment: Unique ID should provide users with an info of the city, company requirements.

Comment: There are only 5 cities Joe.

Comment: What happens when an employee changes cities?

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: you cannot

Comment: @DanBracuk His/her ID changes as well.

Comment: What if you are interested in events from the city from which he moved?

Comment: Are IDs supposed to be unique **alone** (as implied by your usage of the term "auto-increment", which has very specific connotations in database context), or not? For example can there be both "NewYork23" and "Boston23"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are effectively packing two fields into one and violating the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF#Atomicity) and the 1NF in the process. On top of that, your key is not minimal (so to speak).

Instead, keep two separate fields: ID and CITY.

ID **alone** is the primary key. In your own words, ID is auto-increment, so it alone is unique.

You can easily [concatenate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) ID and CITY together for display purposes in your query or VIEW or even in the client code. There is no reason to "precook" the concatenated value in the table itself.

Answer (score 4):

That is not good database design. You really should have a separate column for the city in your table. If you have many cities, the cities should perhaps be in their own table. What you are trying to do is overly complex and although 'everything is possible', I would not recommend it.

Comment: "the cities should perhaps be in their own table" --- how about going further and separating them by datacenters? One city per datacenter. Sounds nice doesn't it?

Comment: Sure, if that's what the structure of your data requires. I would say satisfying BCNF is usually a good enough aim. Some db's require more normalisation, some less.

Comment: I would probably separate the city, and use concatenated primary key.

Comment: I personally don't think how "create a separate table per entry" is not destructive when is being said to a newbie. Is there anything particularly wrong in storing the same type of entities in a single table?

Comment: @user2703038: Why do you want a concatenated PK? Leave the autoincrement PK alone and create a secondary UNIQUE column if you need something more human-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Given this requirement from the comments, "Unique ID should provide users with an info of the city, company requirements", I would do this.

table employee would have an employeeID as the primary key.  Other fields would be firstname, lastname, birthdate, gender, etc

table city would have a cityId as the primary key.  Other fields would be the name of the city, provinceState, Country, whatever is appropriate.

Table EmployeeCity would have have a primary key of EmployeeId, CityId, and StartDate.  Not part of the primary key would be field EndDate.

The primary key of EmployeeCity satisfies the requirement of a unique identifier which leads to city information.  Also, if an employee changes cities, it's a simple matter of updating one record and adding another.